# Encoding video in Azure Media Services with chapter or timeline markers

Tags: azure, video-streaming, html5-video, azure-media-services

Is it possible to encode video in Azure Media Services with chapter or timeline markers, and if so, how?

I understand that custom encoding presets are supported. Outside of Azure Media Services, I was able to do what I am speaking of using the Microsoft Expression Encoder SDK, but I have yet to find this capability in Azure's offerings.

Comment: Your question does not really suits the StackOverflow idea! Check http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask for reference. On a side note, my finding is that Azure Media Encoder / Encryptor is actually a version or built on top of Expression Encoder. So if, you are able to exact the XML of task definition you do in Expression. Modify it a bit to fit the Azure encoder, you might get it working. I have some blog posts for features that were not there back in April-May Last year: http://bit.ly/14527r5 and http://bit.ly/1ACXIqY

Comment: I thank you for your comment. However, I non-argumentatively disagree that it does not belong on SO. This is not an opinion question, and it does not leave much subjectivity other than a person's opinion on a more practical solution. I am asking if it is possible and how? I am seeking "a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development," mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Again, I thank you for your response.

Comment: `I would be interested to see what is possible ...` does not impose simple answerable question...

Comment: Noted. I have removed that line as it could have been better stated that I am looking for the solution(s) (or to be pointed in the right direction) for adding markers for all of the encoding formats, not just smooth streaming. I am _not_ looking for a broad "what is possible" for the encoding formats. I am simply looking for a "how" to do it as @AzureMediaServicesPMteam has provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What do you intend to do with the chapter/timeline markers? If you intend to generate a progressive download MP4 (or WMV) file, then the above response holds. You can modify any of the published presets (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn619392.aspx) for Azure Media Encoder with the Markers element:

```
<MediaFile ...>
<Markers
  MergeCollection="False">
  <Marker
    Time="00:00:00"
    Value="ABC"
    GenerateKeyFrame="True"
    GenerateThumbnail="True" />
  <Marker
    Time="00:00:03.0000000"
    Value="DEF"
    GenerateKeyFrame="True"
    GenerateThumbnail="True" />
</Markers>
<OutputFormat>
```

...

You would have to ensure that the Marker entries were within the timeline of the input video, of course.

Comment: Thank you for you response! Please allow me some time to try this out.

Comment: I haven't had a chance to try this out as I've been put on a separate project. I will take your word for it and accept the answer.